# Favicon in subfolder on Magento Site

Tags: ce-1.9.2.3, favicons

Magento is installed in my root domain: mydomain.com

My support/ticket system is in mydomain.com/support

My favicon is correct in magento and support

BUT, when someone opens a .pdf file in my support system, the favicon is magento.

How do I force the favicon to be my favicon when a pdf is opened?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a redirect on server for favicon file (htaccess or nginx config). There is no way to set a favicon different than default in root folder for non-html file opened in browser.

Comment: from the magento site @ mydomain.com the favicon.ico is correct
but obviously magento is forcing a different default favicon that only appears when opening .pdf files

Comment: exactly, that's why I suggest doing it on server side, that all request to /favicon.ico will go to your custom path. this way you should go around default browser settings